# Curved hair does not move behind the bone

Tags: rigging, bones, bezier-curves, hair

I created the hair using a curve. I can attach the hairstyle to the hair without weights, but the hair in the ears does not work even when combined with the body. When I try to connect them, I write from above that no solution has been found for one or more bones. I select hair and bones, press ctrl p and select automatic weights. Then I get the error Bone Heat Weighing: Could not find a solution for one or more bones.
"The same thing happens even if I combine my hair and body. [image][image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you try to edit and explain with more detail what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and also more screenshots (the one you posted is very jumbled and it's hard to tell what I'm looking at).

Comment: Look for an error message in Blender when you try to parent with automatic weights.  I suspect you'll see "Bone heat failure".  The error message should get you started on your research.